# bash/zsh: Is it possible to prevent auto-inclusion of a slash when using tabs to autocomplete a path?

Tags: bash, zsh, autocomplete

When I use tab to autocomplete a path, a trailing slash is automatically added.

I checked both bash and ZSH and I get the same behavior. Is it possible to prevent this?

I check unsetopt and I have "noautoparamslash" already unset.

```
$ unsetopt | grep param       
noautoparamkeys
noautoparamslash
```

Thanks

edit1: The terminal output above was done on a zsh shell session.

Comment: Please don't mix bash and zsh in the same question in a case like this where the two shells behave completely differently. Their completion systems are completely different, so these are two different questions. Pick one.

Comment: In zsh, if `unsetopt` shows `noautoparamslash`, it means that `noautoparamslash` is unset, i.e. `autoparamslash` is set (yes, it's a bit confusing). That being said, this only affects what happens when completing a _parameter_, i.e. after `cat $foo<Tab>` when the value of `$foo` is a directory. Are you using the “old” completion system (`compctl`) or the “new” completion system (`compinit`)?

Comment: In Bash try `bind 'set mark-directories off'`

Comment: @Gilles not sure what completion I'm using. I'm installed latest ZSH on macOS using homebrew and loading this plugin via antigen https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions